# C# AspNetCore WebApp. Настройка байндинга для POST запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Если у меня есть модель данных в которой есть св-во представленное абстрактным классом.
Если я возвращаю ответ GET запросом, то JSON сериализатор рабоатет корректно.
Если я этот JSON передаю в POST запросе, то привязка не может понять какой объект я передал для абстрактного класса и в итоге в метод прилетает null.

```
public class ExchangeOptionDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool AutoStartCycleFunc { get; set; }        
    public ProviderBaseDto Provider { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ProviderBaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class ManualProviderDto : ProviderBaseDto
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int TimeRespone { get; set; }
}

public class ByRulesProviderDto : ProviderBaseDto
{
    public List<RuleDto> RulesDto { get; set; }
}

public class RuleDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public RequestDto Request { get; set; }    
    public ResponseDto Response { get; set; }
}
```

RequestDto и ResponseDto - не привожу (POCO классы)

**GET метод контроллера:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ExchangeOptionDto Get()
{
    var exch = new ExchangeOptionDto
    {
        Id = 1,
        Key = "Exch_1",
        AutoStartCycleFunc = true,
        Provider = new ManualProvider
        {
            Name = "VidorBase",
            Address = "41",
            TimeRespone = 1000
        }
    };
    return exch;
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "key": "Exch_1",
        "autoStartCycleFunc": true,
            "provider": {
            "address": "41",
            "timeRespone": 1000,
            "name": "VidorBase"
        }
    }
```

Если этот же JSON передать в теле POST запроса то будет null.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]ExchangeOptionDto value)
    {
        var exch = value;  
    }
```

Я так понимаю, в качестве DTO нужно передавать только POCO объекты?
Или, как то можно настроить поведение привязки для конкретного типа DTO?

Comment: Передавать лучше только простые дто объекты. Но вы можете конечно и биндер перенастроить или сериализатор свой написать, но это то же самое, что лопатой гвозди забивать. Общая рекомендация - контракты ваших сервисов должны быть максимально простыми, добавляя наследования или поведение своим дто объектам вы только сами себе яму роете на ровном месте.

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо теперь я в этом точно уверен)).

Comment: Вообще, можно настроить байндинг. Для этого нужно поиграться с `TypeNameHandling` и прочим. Но лучше действительно не мучиться и использовать POCO.